# How to correctly pass object by type from C# to VBScript?

Tags: c#, vbscript, com

How to pass C# object to VBScript?

My C# class, that I want return is:

```
namespace GSM
{

    [Guid("9E5E5FB2-219D-4ee7-AB27-E4DBED8E125E")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ProgId("GSM.ParseResult")]
    public class ParseResult
    {
        public string Status;
        public HtmlNode table;

    }
}
```

I've Googled a lot of sites and most of them recommend to pass `object[]` as C# return value. In this case VBScript iterates and reconizes object types and values well. For example, the function, that returns it is something like this:

```
public object[] Parse(string userid, string password, string startDate, string endDate)
        {
            ParseResult parseResult = new ParseResult();
            parseResult.Status="OK";   

            object o = (object)parseResult;
            object[] oa = new object[] { o };
            return oa;     
        }
```

and VBScript, that working with it well:

```
Dim o
Set o = CreateObject("1C_GSM.TestComClass")
Dim a
a = o.Parse("51597", "********", "01-03-2017", "31-03-2017")
For Each entry In a
                Wscript.Echo TypeName(entry)
                Wscript.Echo entry
                Wscript.Echo entry.Status
Next
```

In this case three messages will be shown: `ParseResult`, `GSM.ParseResult` and `OK`.

But when I trying to change my function to

```
public ParseResult Parse(string userid, string password, string startDate, string endDate)
            {
                ParseResult parseResult = new ParseResult();
                parseResult.Status="OK"; 

                return parseResult;     
            }
```

and trying to call it in VBScript with code

```
Dim o
Set o = CreateObject("1C_GSM.TestComClass")
Dim a
a = o.Parse("51597", "********", "01-03-2017", "31-03-2017")
Wscript.Echo TypeName(a)
Wscript.Echo a
Wscript.Echo a.Status
```

messages will be are: `String`, `GSM.ParseResult` and message about exception with code 800A01A8 for line `Wscript.Echo a.Status`.

Why VBScript recognizes type of returned object as String, and no as my class type, if object was returned directly, but reconizes type as `ParseResult`, if returned value was wrapped to `object[]`?

How to force VBScript to recognize the type of returned object as `ParseResult` without wrapping it into the `object[]`?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use `ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual` or `ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch` for your class?

Comment: What happens if you do `Set a = o.Parse(...)` instead of `a = o.Parse(...)`?

Comment: I've tried them both, but those changes didn't solve the issue...

Comment: Michael Gunter, you are my time saver! Thank you very much! Can you make it as an answer for this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself for this, but you just need to use `Set a = o.Parse(...)` instead of `a = o.Parse(...)`.

For those wondering why: `a = o.Parse(...)` is implicitly `Let a = o.Parse(...)`. `Let` is used when assigning values, and `Set` is used when assigning objects. When using `Let` to assign an object, it's going to convert the object to a value. I don't recall the mechanism, but it probably uses standard COM techniques involving things like [`IDispatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221608(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`DISPID_VALUE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221242(v=vs.85).aspx). When this conversion is invoked, something in the .NET framework is either returning the ProgID or the full .NET Namespace.ClassName of your object.

Comment: Without the Set it will try to use the default value of the object instead of the object reference.  It doesn't have one, kaboom.  The syntax ambiguity was fixed in vb.net, a Default property must always be an indexed property.